# Getting wrong value from solidity function

Tags: solidity, javascript

I have multiple functions in javascript

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(event){
            showData();
            CheckIfVoted();
        })

        function showData(){
            voting.methods.GetVotes().call().then(function(result){
                let votes = [...document.querySelector("#Results").children];
                for (let i=0;i<votes.length;i++){
                    votes[i].innerHTML = result[i];
                }
            })
        }

        function CheckIfVoted(){ 
            voting.methods.AlreadyVoted().call({from:web3.eth.defaultAccount}).then(function(result){
                console.log(result);
                if (result){
                    let btn = document.querySelector("button");
                    btn.disabled = true;
                    btn.innerText = "Вы уже проголосовали";
                };
            });
        }

        function voteFaculty(){
            voting.methods.vote(Number(document.querySelector("option:checked").value)).send({from:web3.eth.defaultAccount});
            console.log(Number(document.querySelector("option:checked").value));
        }
```

and i have solidity contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract FacultyVoting
{
    mapping(address => bool) private voters;
    uint32[11] private faculties;
    
    event Voted(uint32 faculty);
    event VoteFailed(uint32 faculty);
    
    function vote(uint32 faculty) public
    {
        require(voters[msg.sender]==false,"Вы уже проголосовали");
        require(faculty < 11, "Неверный факультет");
        
        voters[msg.sender] = true;
        ++faculties[faculty];
        emit Voted(faculty);
    }
    
    function AlreadyVoted() public view returns (bool)
    {
        return voters[msg.sender];
    }
    
    function GetVotes() public view returns (uint32[11]){
        return faculties;
    }  
    
     
}
```

I'm trying to achieve so after one transaction you won't be able to do more transaction, also the html changes through js. For some reason vote function in solidity works fine so you cant do more transactions as metamask throws exception, but calling AlreadyVoted function in js doesn't seem to be working properly, as it always returns false value, even if you already did one transaction.

I'm a newbie at solidity and also english is not my first language, so sorry if question is stupid/incorrect.